# How to band limit a wav signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I imported a .wav signal to Matlab workspace, I am then asked to "band limit" the signal using a fourth order Butterworth filter but I am not really sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you have signal processing toolbox? If you have and you understand the theory behind the filtering, then you can play with the gui tools that come with the toolbox like `filterbuilder` and get your filter right, then if you need you can expert it and use the code elsewhere or write the code easily.

Comment: I am specified to use the command 'butter', now My question is, how do I use 'butter' to band limit a wav signal ??

Comment: Butter designs the filter, there is excellent documentation here: <http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/butter.html> please read and tell us which part you have difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first read the documentation of the Matlab function [`butter`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/signal/ref/butter.html) (which is in the Signal processing Toolbox).

This function is used to design a Butterworth filter. One of the possible syntax is:

```
[b a]=butter(n,Wn,'ftype');
```

- b and a are coefficients of a digital filter that can be used with the function [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html)
- n is the order of the filter, except in the case of a bandstop or bandpass filter in which case the order is 2*n
- Wn is the cutoff frequency, if you want to design a bandstop or a bandpass filter it can be a 2 elements vector. The cutoff frequency is expected to be between 0 and 1, where 1 represents the Nyquist frequency

Now if you want to apply this to your case, you could do something like this:

```
% Read wav file (store sampling frequency in fs)
[data fs]=wavread('sample.wav');
% Design a 4th order lowpass filter with a cutoff frequency of 5000 Hz 
% (notice how the cutoff frequency is scaled by the Nyquist frequency fs/2)
n=4;
Wn=5000*2/fs;
[b a]=butter(n,Wn,'low');
% Apply the filter to the data
datafilt=filter(b,a,data);
```

Comment: Great, But I have a couple pf questions, when I read the .wav file my syntax was '[data fs]=wavread('sample.wav')' I dont understand why do I need to use the nbits , and also its says in the problem to BAND LIMIT the signal to 5000Hz , so Iam supposed to use a low pass filter instead of bandpass, and therefore it would be like:

Wn = 5000 / (fs/2);
[b,a] = butter(4,Wn,'low')
datafilt=filter(b,a,data);
Is that correct ??

Comment: Of course you can discard the number of bits and use your syntax, as long as you keep the sampling frequency which is used to design the filter. Indeed if you want to design a lowpass filter, then Wn is a scalar and ftype='low'. I will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: ok thanks,but I just want to make sure when he says band limit, then Iam supposed to use a lowpass filter, right